# Unit testing object mapper method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

I was told that I should unit test this method but I'm not sure how? How would I unit test a method that only maps a JSON string to a DTO. The String line I will get from a Kafka topic through a Kafkalistener.

```
    public void Mapper(String line) {

    try {
        LeadTimeDTO leadTimeDTO = objectMapper.readValue(line, LeadTimeDTO.class);
        
        System.out.println("leadTimeDTO:" + leadTimeDTO);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error parsing to DTO");

    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to test that `System.out.println` is called, and inspects its contents, you can use https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/standard-input-output/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JUnit5:

I would start by checking that `objectMapper.readValue` doesn't throw any exception:

```
assertDoesNotThrow(() -> objectMapper.readValue(line, LeadTimeDTO.class));
```

Then, check mapped object is not null:

```
assertThat(leadTimeDTO).isNotNul();
```

After that, you can check the fields are being populated correctly by using

```
assertThat(leadTimeDTO.getName()).isEqualTo("Some name");
```

Comment: That will only be possible if the `objectMapper` and its result are available outside this method.

Comment: @RobSpoor im mapping the string to a Dto class. What do you mean exactly by your statement? And why do you think this approach will not work. Thanks a lot

Comment: In this case `objectMapper` is outside of the scope of this method. The answer will work even if `objectMapper` and the output is in the scope of the method,